# How to get quotient in integer division in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I wonder how to get quotient in integer division in MATLAB? Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [idivide](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/idivide.html):

> C = idivide(A, B) is the same as A./B except that fractional quotients are rounded toward zero to the nearest integers.

There's a third optional parameter for controlling the rounding behavior that's explained on the MathWorks site that I linked to.

Answer (score 4):

Simply, put as following:

```
floor(A/B)
```

floor command rounds the value to the nearest integer, towards negative infinity (`-inf`).

Answer (score 2):

just divide and round down?

or are you talking about integer division, in which case use `idivide`

Comment: I believe you meant to say `idivide`, not `divideint`: http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/idivide.html